# How to get specific elements from an file whose structure is XML-like in Java

Tags: java, xml, file, substring

I have a .sic-File whose structure is like XML but not completely. There I have a section `Channel2` where I want to read some elements. The section is like this:

```
.
.
.
<SI name = "Channel2" type = "list">
           <SI name = "SecsPortConfig" type = "list">
              <SI name = "PortType" type = "string">'XXX'</SI>
              <SI name = "Protocol" type = "string">'XXX'</SI>
              <SI name = "Serial" type = "list">
                 <SI name = "Port" type = "int">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "Speed" type = "int">'XXXX'</SI>
              </SI>
              <SI name = "Socket" type = "list">
                 <SI name = "ConnectionMode" type = "string">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "LocalHost" type = "string">'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "LocalPort" type = "int">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "RemoteHost" type = "string">'XXX.XXX.XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "RemotePort" type = "int">'XXX'</SI>
              </SI>
              <SI name = "HSMS" type = "list">
                 <SI name = "T5" type = "int">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "T6" type = "int">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "T7" type = "int">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "T8" type = "int">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "LinkTestTime" type = "int">'XXX'</SI>
              </SI>
              <SI name = "SECSI" type = "list">
                 <SI name = "T1" type = "int">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "T2" type = "int">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "T4" type = "int">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "RTY" type = "int">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "IsHost" type = "bool">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "IsMaster" type = "bool">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "InterleaveBlocks" type = "bool">'XXX'</SI>
              </SI>
              <SI name = "SECSII" type = "list">
                 <SI name = "DeviceID" type = "int">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "T3" type = "int">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "MultipleOpen" type = "bool">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "AutoDeviceID" type = "bool">'XXX'</SI>
              </SI>
              <SI name = "Log" type = "list">
                 <SI name = "LogCharError" type = "bool">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "LogCharEvent" type = "bool">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "LogCharReceive" type = "bool">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "LogCharSend" type = "bool">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "LogSecsIHsmsError" type = "bool">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "LogSecsIHsmsEvent" type = "bool">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "LogSecsIHsmsReceive" type = "bool">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "LogSecsIHsmsSend" type = "bool">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "LogSecsIIError" type = "bool">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "LogSecsIIEvent" type = "bool">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "LogSecsIIReceive" type = "bool">'XXX'</SI>
                 <SI name = "LogSecsIISend" type = "bool">'XXX'</SI>
              </SI>
           </SI>
           <SI name = "UseSeparateSECSLogFile" type = "bool">'XXX'</SI>
           <SI name = "Connected" type = "bool">'XXX'</SI>
           <SI name = "MessageFilters" type = "list">
              <SI name = "DeviceIDList" type = "list"/>
              <SI name = "StreamFunctionList" type = "list"/>
           </SI>
           <SI name = "SafeMessageFilters" type = "list">
              <SI name = "DeviceIDList" type = "list"/>
              <SI name = "StreamFunctionList" type = "list"/>
           </SI>
        </SI>
        .
        .
        .
```

If it would be an xml-file I could parse it and read out the elements, but how do I do it with this kind of file?
I want to extract the elements `RemoteHost` and `RemotePort`.
I tried it now with a BufferedReader and I get the Section `Channel2` from the file with inserting this section in a String, but how do I extract the specific values of the elements I want? I could probably do it with substring and some other String-methods, but is there no easier way to do it?
This is my code so far:

```
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\but\\Desktop\\ExternalswPassThroughSrv.sic");

    int counter = 0;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    String cl;
    String finalString = "";
    while ((cl = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (cl.contains("Channel2")) {
            counter = 63;
        }
        if(counter != 0){
            //System.out.println(cl);
            finalString += cl + "\n";
            counter--;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(finalString);
```

Comment: "how do I do it with this kind of file?" - just like with every other xml file. Have you looked into parsing this file and how to find elements using an xpath statement?

Comment: Maybe I'm blind... but, why is this no XML-File?

Comment: The part you've shown us appears to be well-formed XML. I'm mystified what this question is about.

Comment: it is formed as xml, but they are not tagged like normal xml. How should I get the elements when I use the DOM parser? I can parse it, but methods like getElementsByTagName cant read the element. A normal xml-file would look like this:
'<employees>
    <employee id="111">
        <firstName>Lokesh</firstName>
        <lastName>Gupta</lastName>
        <location>India</location>
    </employee>
    .
    .'

The file I want to read always starts with SI name, so I dont know how to access the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we don't know how the whole file is formed:
Even if it is not a complete XML document, you can extract the XML-Fragment from the rest of the file and convert it to a well formed XML-Document by adding a root element.

After that you can parse it into a Document and use XPath to extract the wanted information.

Here is some example Java code that could work for you (I didn't include the xml, for clarity)

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class ConvertXml {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException, TransformerException, XPathExpressionException {
        // Your XML-like content
        String xmlString = "xml here";

        // transform xml-Fragment into well-formed xml with root element
        String xmlStringWellformed = "<content>" + xmlString + "</content>";

        // parse well-formed xml
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlStringWellformed)));

        // build xpath expression
        String xPathRemoteHost = "//SI[@name='Channel2']/SI[@name='SecsPortConfig']/SI[@name='Socket']/SI[@name='RemoteHost']/text()";
        String xPathRemotePort = "//SI[@name='Channel2']/SI[@name='SecsPortConfig']/SI[@name='Socket']/SI[@name='RemotePort']/text()";
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        // Use XPath for extraction
        String remoteHost = (String) xPath.compile(xPathRemoteHost).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
        String remotePort = (String) xPath.compile(xPathRemotePort).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);

        System.out.println("RemoteHost: " + remoteHost);
        System.out.println("RemotePort: " + remotePort);
    }
}
```

Sources:
[Baeldung - Intro to XPath with Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-xpath)

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I switched to python and solved the problem but I would have to implement the python code in java with jython. With this I can do it without using python. I tried it out now and it works perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 1):

```java
Document _myDoc = null;

LSInput input  = implLS.createLSInput();

input.setStringData(requestXML);

_myDoc = parser.parse(input);

SI = ((NodeList)_myDoc.getElementsByTagName("MessageFilters")).item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

you can get the node values of XML element by using getElementsByTagName. But for that you need to have different element names.This is not the answer. This is not the answer.just a hint.try out this.